# Import npm module as source code

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, vue.js

I want to import the source code for [vue-form-generator](https://github.com/vue-generators/vue-form-generator) to make some changes to the source code. Being new to Node and Javascript, I really have no idea what I'm doing. Can someone please guide me through the steps?

Since my Vue project is in Typescript, previously when I was using `npm install vue-form-generator` I'd created vfg.d.ts

```
declare module "vue-form-generator" {
  const VueFormGenerator: any;
  export default VueFormGenerator;
}
```

and my `main.ts` was

```
import VueFormGenerator from 'vue-form-generator';
Vue.component('VueFormGenerator', VueFormGenerator);
```

Now I have copied everything from their /src to my /src/component/form-generator but have no idea how to make it so I can use  as previously.

Comment: I don't understand why you're not just doing the `npm install` approach still?

Comment: @Paul I need to change the way they are generating the templates for each input and to my knowledge there's no facility provided in their version for that so I need to change the source code in formGenerator.vue

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating your own fork of `vue-form-generator`, you may add type declarations right there as well.

create file `index.d.ts` in your copy of `src/component/form-generator`:

```
  const VueFormGenerator: any;
  export default VueFormGenerator;
```

There is no need to have `declare module ...` in there because this `index.d.ts` is right next to `index.js`, so TypeScript compiler should find it when you import it as

```
import VueFormGenerator from './relative-path-to/form-generator/index';
```

and generated javascript code will find it as `index.js` there. Note that the import path must be relative because otherwise, without any path mapping, it will look for the module in `node_modules`, not in your sources.

You also have to remove all references to the previous type declaration file, `vfg.d.ts`, in your project.